# I want update my android app when new version find in my web server from my web server but its not installing

Tags: android, android-intent

Inside my android application I have created a service that will check on my web server, if new version application will found it will update my application.
**but I cannot install or my installation is unsuccessfull untill i uninstall the privious version.**

my new version installation code is:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);          
promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/apks/PHS_TKS_v3.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

and user permission in manifest is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
```

I am trying to install new version apk not same version
If i install manually its not installing if older version is installed.

Comment: Do you see an error in LogCat?

Comment: Priyank: just 'cos it gives me the twitches, if you're correcting grammar and spelling please spell "grammar" correctly in your edit messages :-P

Comment: no any error is showing, if i install manually its not installing if old version is installed.(sorry for bad english)

Comment: No errors in LogCat but in emulater (4.1) showing error msg when I confirm instalation is that "an exising package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed".

Comment: But I am installing new version apk file

Answer (score 1):

The error msg "an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed" means, that you have the application installed already, but it was built with a different signature.
If you were building and debugging in eclipse, then it pushed the apk to your phone with the debug or test keys.
You need to uninstall the app, then installed a version that was built using your custom keystore